# HTML tab content as plot objects

Tags: javascript, html

I am using leaflet popup to triger drawing of various graphs via onEachFeature event:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(content,{minWidth : 800})
        .on('popupopen', function (e) {
            load_pl_wind(feature.properties.id,map)
        })
}
```

function `load_pl_wind` generates `myDiv` object, which is a simple Plotly object. I have set variable `content` to following:

```
var content = '<div class="tabs">' +

'<div class="tab" id="tab-1" >' +
'<div class="content" >' +
    '<div> id="myDiv"</div>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>' +

'<div class="tab" id="tab-2">' +
    '<canvas id="myDiv" class="chart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>' +
'</div>' +

'<ul class="tabs-link">' +
'<li class="tab-link"> <a href="#tab-1"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>' +
'<li class="tab-link"> <a href="#tab-2"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>' +
'</ul>' +
'</div>';
```

I get following output, when I click on any of both links for Tab 1 or Tab 2:
[image]

However, if set variable content simply to

```
var content = '<div id="myDiv" </div>'
```

I get appropriate output, but without tabs as expected.

[image]

How can I display `myDiv` object inside Tab?

Comment: `id="myDiv"` you specify as text between div tags. Try this - `<div id="myDiv"></div>`

Comment: that showed the graph, but it doesn't cycle between tabs. I tried to add javascript function as shown here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs) using similar technique ( inserting as text and running with popup, but function onclick event is not recognized.